# close button ('x') not appearing inside the autocomplete angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Close button ('x') not appearing inside the autocomplete (angular material),
  please provide some solution to solve this problem.

[here is my screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19yU6.png)

Comment: This is not an issue with angularjs. What plugin you are using for autocomplete?

Comment: i am using the locally hosted files(angular.min.css,angular.min.js)

Comment: it's rendering, so you could just move it with CSS

Comment: Autocomplete input widget is not a part of angularjs. Which libray/plugin/directive you are using for this?

Comment: how to move it with CSS, Could you  please post your code.

Comment: i am new to angularjs and angular material so please explain clearly.

Comment: Got it, so you are using angular material :) Please provide which one you are using and how you are using? https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete

Comment: I am using <md-autocomplete> the first one in angular material framework demo

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I solved it by using new version of angular-material library.